# Create a function that receives a word as string and returns an encoded output that contains number of occurrence of each element in this word

Tags: python

Create a function that receives a word as string and returns an encoded output that contains number of occurrence of each element in this word until we find a deferential element in this word

Constraints:
the input must:

- have a length that is :   0 < length  <= 15000
- be lower
- alpha

**Examples** :
input : "aabssd"
output : 2a1b2s1d

input : "aabssdaabbbb"
output : 2a1b2s1d2a4b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so I created two functions,

**the first one** encodes my text, and I implemented as follow :

```
def encode(text):

if(len(text)==1):
  return "1"+text
if(len(set(text))== 1):
  return str(len(text))+text[0]

mylist = []
listOccu = []
sum = 0
x=text[0]
for i in range(len(text)):
  if x == text[i]:
    sum = sum+1
  else:
    mylist.append(text[i-1])
    listOccu.append(sum)
    x=text[i]
    sum = 1
    fin=i

myencode=''    
for i,j in enumerate(listOccu):
  myencode = myencode+str(j)+str(mylist[i])
myencode = myencode+str(len(text[fin:]))+text[fin]
return myencode
```

and **the second one** is to check if the input text contains the letters from [a,z] and has a max size < 15000 "

```
def prepare_text():
text=''

while text.islower() == False or text.isalpha() == False or len(text) > 15000 or len(text)==0 :
  text=str(input("input a text that contains letters from [a,z] and has a max size of 15000    "))

myEncodedText = encode(text)
print(myEncodedText)
prepare_text()
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: @PedroMaia yes, I did it with this way

Comment: Why do you need to check the length? It's not a recursive function.

Comment: @MSH it's just a constraint that was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In this code I used the **count** function to ease up the process and then use a new string to store the encoded text, so that the original string remains the same. Here is the code:

```
def encode(s):
  strocc = []
  news = ''
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if(s[i] not in strocc):
      news+=str(s.count(s[i]))+s[i]
      strocc.append(s[i])
  return news
s='aabssd'
print(encode(s))
```

Comment: it's not what I want, for example if I used your solution for this input "aabssdaa" I will get : 4a1b2s1d, insted I want to have as output "2a1b2s1d2a"

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions, `set`s and string's `count` and `join` methods.

First loop in the unique elements of the string. To achieve that you can use `set` and sorted to sort the set:

```
sorted(set(txt))
```

Now you have sorted unique elements, you can check how many time each element is accruing and appending them to a list:

```
[f"{txt.count(t)}{t}" for t in sorted(set(txt))]
```

Now you can join the list into a string:

```
"".join([f"{txt.count(t)}{t}" for t in sorted(set(txt))])
```

Test:

```
txt = "aabbcnff"
a = "".join([f"{txt.count(t)}{t}" for t in sorted(set(txt))])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
2a2b1c2f1n
```